# How to Set Spectrum Transparency

Tags: jquery, transparency, spectrum

I'm using the **jquery.spectrum** color picker plugin.  I want to be able to retrieve and set the alpha channel along with **rgb**.

I can successfully get the alpha value that the user sets, but am having a great deal of trouble setting it.

If I set the alpha channel to anything but 0, it automatically goes to 255.

I've tried a variety of formats such as `{a: xx, r: xx, g: xx, b: xx}`, `argb`, `rgba`, etc., but have been unable to get any variation for `a > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

With a clearer head this morning, the answer is obvious:

Whereas the `get` produces an answer between 0 and 255, the `set` wants to see a value between 0 and 1.